# Error in installation of spark NLP for Healthcare

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pip, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

As per https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/docs/en/licensed_install, the command to install spark-nlp-jsl is as below.
`pip install -q spark-nlp-jsl==${version} --extra-index-url https://pypi.johnsnowlabs.com/${secret.code} --upgrade`

I tried by providing a version as **3.0.2** and my **{secret.code}** but getting the below error:
Collecting spark-nlp-jsl==3.0.2
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

````
  status = self.run(options, args)<br/>
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run<br/>
  wb.build(autobuilding=True)<br/>
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build<br/>
  self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)<br/>
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files<br/>
  ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))<br/>
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file<br/>
  require_hashes<br/>
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link<br/>
  self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)<br/>
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement<br/>
  all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)<br/>
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates<br/>
  for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):<br/>
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages<br/>
  page = self._get_page(location)<br/>
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page<br/>
  return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)<br/>
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 795, in get_page<br/>
  resp.raise_for_status()<br/>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status<br/>
  raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)<br/>
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404<br/>
Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/spark-nlp-jsl/```


I am new to Python and SparkNLP so any pointer/help is much appreciated.
````

Comment: Sometimes upgrading PIP, 

pip install --upgrade pip

may help

Answer (score 0):

check that the version you use, and the first part of the secret code must match.
So,

python3 -m pip install --upgrade spark-nlp-jsl==**3.0.2** --user --extra-index-url https://pypi.johnsnowlabs.com/3.0.2-XXXXXSECRETXXXXX